# In Nuxt 3, can I specify a global sub-directory for all routing

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I would like to specify a global sub-directory that precedes all routing, for both client and API endpoints. So:

https://my-site.com/dir/api/* (for all API routes)
https://my-site.com/dir/somepage

I would like to control this at a routing level vs. a deployment level. Is there a good way to configure it as such?